# ¿Qué significa "che"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, definiciones, argentina

Según he escuchado, la palabra "che" viene de Argentina y se usa para referirse a alguien. Lo que no sé bien es de qué forma se usa esta palabra. También existe "El Che" para referirse a [Ernesto (Che) Guevara de la Serna](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Che_Guevara), a quien conocían así por ser argentino. ¿Cómo se usa esta palabra y qué significa?

Comment: En Chile, "che" significa "argentino" por metonimia. _Santiago se llenó de chés este verano_. _Me compré una chaqueta ché_ (o sea una chaqueta _argentina_).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En Argentina, *che* es una interjección y puede funcionar como un vocativo; en ocasiones es difícil distinguir entre una y otra función. Como interjección suele usarse para llamar la atención sobre algo negativo o inesperado, con lo cual termina asociado a adversativos:

- *¡Che, esto no sirve, está todo roto!*
- *Pero si llegué temprano, che, cómo puede ser que no me hayan esperado...*
- *¿No será mucho, che?*

(*¿No será mucho?* es una frase idiomática.)

Como vocativo puede ir reforzando el nombre propio o no:

- *Vení, che, sentate un rato con nosotros.*
- *Che, Martín, ¿dónde dijiste que te ibas de vacaciones?*
- *Che, no toquen ahí que está fresca la pintura.*
- *Che, gente, hoy tengo que salir temprano.*

Nótese cómo las funciones se confunden: a veces *che* se usa simplemente como muletilla inicial para hacer que los oyentes presten atención, como un "hey" inglés o un carraspeo.

*Che* no se usa en Argentina como sustantivo. No tiene género ni número (sirve como vocativo para una persona o más y de cualquier género). El apelativo "Che" de Ernesto Guevara le fue impuesto por hablantes no argentinos.

Entiendo que hay varias hipótesis sobre el origen de *che*, siendo la más difundida la que dice que proviene del término mapudungun *che* que significa "gente" (el mapudungun o mapuzungun es el idioma del pueblo llamado habitualmente *mapuche*, donde aparece justamente ese morfema, al igual que en el nombre de la ciudad de Bariloche). Esto es completamente inverosímil. Se puede leer más al respecto en [el artículo de Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Che).

Answer (score 8):

Se podría hacer una comparación de "che" con el estadounidense "hey".

Como significar, no significa nada. De todas maneras, muchas veces para llamar a alguien (conocido) se le dice por ejemplo "¡che! vení acá".

No se lo utiliza para hablar de una tercera persona.

Comment: ¡Buena respuesta, user! Bienvenido a [spanish.se], esperamos verte con frecuencia. Dale un vistazo al [tour] para aprender más del sitio :)

Answer (score 8):

Según la RAE:

> **[che](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=8gKEtDx)**
>
> De *che*, voz con que se llama a personas y animales.
>
> 1. interj. Val., Arg., Bol., Par. y Ur. U. para llamar, detener o pedir atención a alguien, o para denotar asombro o sorpresa.

Su origen es simplemente fonético, un sonido o voz usado para llamar la atención de alguien (o algo). Es equivalente a "eh", "epa" y otros similares.

El porqué de su prevalencia en algunas zonas (Valencia dentro de España, o Argentina en general) y no en otras, se me escapa.
En Argentina puede ser por influencia de unos primeros pocos colonos que la usasen, o porque al ser tierra de mucho caballo y ganado es más habitual el uso de este tipo de expresiones.

Comment: Bien, pero no estoy muy de acuerdo en que sea equivalente a "eh", "epa" ... "che" siempre *interpela a una segunda persona*.